# check whether a number is prime ,even or odd using function

Tags: c++, function

i am trying to make a program that will check whether the number is odd ,even or prime.But its giving error saying"no match for 'operator>>'".
Is their any other why I can do it? .Or can someone please  help me to find the error an solve it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


   void cal(int a, int b,char op)
   {
       switch(op)
       {
           case'+':
           cout<<a<<"+"<<b<<"="<<a+b<<endl;
           break;
           case'-':
           cout<<a<<"-"<<b<<"="<<a-b<<endl;
           break;
           case'*':
           cout<<a<<"*"<<b<<"="<<a*b<<endl;
           break;
           case'/':
          cout<<a<<"/"<<b<<"="<<a/b<<endl;
          break;
          case'%':
          cout<<a<<"%"<<b<<"="<<a%b<<endl;
          break;
          default:
            cout<<"Invalid operator!"<<endl;
       }

       }
       int main()
{

    int a,b;
    char op;
    cout<<"Enter first number,operator and a second number:"<<endl;
    cin>>a>>endl;
    cin>>b>>endl;
    cin>>op>>endl;
    cal(a,b,op);

   }
```

Comment: `cin >> endl;` is nonsense, as your compiler probably told you in no uncertain terms. And you would have seen, if you had some spacing between operators and operands.

Comment: dont use endl in the cin function, and btw cin is recursive so you can just do cin >> a >> b >> op;

Comment: This code has nothing to do with the requested program...

Comment: @DanielKovachev -- `cin` is not a function. It's an object. The `>>`s are functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker `>>` are operators, not functions.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but on output, do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts -- they're **written** as operators, but they are function calls.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, they call a function, but that does not make them "function calls". C++ is predicated on the fact that every operator can be overloaded with a function call, but they are still operators. Please don't call them functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker If you're going to lecture someone else on semantics like "`cin` is not a function, `>>` are", expect to be corrected yourself. You are not above being corrected for an incorrect statement, just because you enjoy playing [tag:language-lawyer].

Comment: @Patrick Roberts - if you're going to try correcting someone, pick someone who knows less than you do.   Pete Becker definitely knows more than you do.   And he is right on all counts here that you are trying to correct him on.

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't do what you are describing, but to solve the compilation issue, you should change the code lines related to cin as follows:

```
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    cin >> op;
```